# React Native: Styling not applying

Tags: react-native, text, styling

I cant understand why styling is not being applied to the `{props.children}` inside view in the following code. Its not throwing any errors but only renders the `{props.children}` as simply text.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {

    borderWidth: 8,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 60
  }
};

export default Card;
```

render `{props.children}` here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';

const AlbumDetail = (props) => (
    <Card>
      <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
    </Card>
  );

export default AlbumDetail;
```

Comment: You aren't applying styles to it's children. Just to the parent itself. You have to provide styles to Text element if you want children (in this case Text) to have those styles.

Comment: Solved Issue: was having an error with metro Bundler that I didnt realise which was causing my project not to update. Restarting metro bundler fixed my issue.

Answer (score 16):

@Murmeltier's answer has tiny error.

Text component has the name of property, 'style', not 'styles'.

```
<Text style={props.album.title}></Text>
```

Comment: I thought I was going nuts. I'm really glad I found your answer. A tiny typo can really mess you up.

Answer (score 1):

You are just passing your nested components to your `AlbumDetail` but you are not applying any style to the `text` inside of your `Card`-component. You should set them like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';

const AlbumDetail = (props) => (
    <Card>
      <Text styles={props.album.title}></Text>
    </Card>
);

export default AlbumDetail;
```